# Base64 decoding - incorrect string length

Tags: c, string, openssl, base64

I'm trying to decode base64-encoded string with openssl. However, it works only 4 times out of 5.

Decoded string should always be 64 chars long. BIO_read() always returns 64. However, sometimes returned buffer is shorter than 64!

Any ideas what is wrong? How can i always get the correct string?

Comment: What do you mean by "returned buffer"? You pass the buffer *into* BIO_read. Sample code would help.

Comment: I mean what BIO_read puts into destination.

Anyway, I tracked down my problem to single character. It looks like sometimes BIO_read returns the same char as terminating. and that kills the string...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using str[n]cpy? You can't! Base64 encoded data can contain null characters, which C string processing functions interpret as end-of-string.

Use memcpy instead of str[n]cpy, memcmp instead of strcmp, etc. These functions require you to know your data size, but I believe that you *do* know it.

Also if you're not very confident about C-style strings and such, there's plenty of information to be found about the topic here.

Comment: Hmmm, isn't base64 encoded data composed entirely of printable characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, '+' and '/' [and '=' for padding])?

Comment: I'm referring to the data that was encoded as Base64 (i.e. what you get back when you Base64 decode), not the Base64 encoded form of the data.